# Android Global Cache

Tags: android, caching

For performance reasons there's a need to cache things between activities (data, resources, etc), passing things in Bundles between activities is messy.

Is there a preferred cache mechanism in Android?

My other thoughts was to break out a singleton and create my own cache utility, but if there's something more elegant within the SDK?

Comment: "passing things in Bundles between activities" is a preferred way of passing data to a started Activity

Comment: Agreed. However it gets unwieldy when there is a need to pass lots of data. I would prefer a Global key/value store solution, rather then passing a big DTO type object between activities..

Comment: so what about extending Application class or custom ContentProvider?